# Why is the rate of induced absorption not equal to the rate of stimulated emission?

Tags: laser

Even though the probability of induced absorption is equal to
the probability of stimulated emission, the rate of induced absorption is
not equal to the rate of stimulated emission. Why?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by rate? I assume it's something proportional to the population in the ground/excited state times the number of photons passing by the atom.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean in an equilibrium situation? The reason is that there is also the process of spontaneous emission to include.

Thus the rates of stimulated plus spontaneous emission equals the rate of absorption.

Note that the probabilities of stimulated emission and absorption are *not* equal, since those probabilities depend on both the relative populations of the upper and lower states, the Einstein coefficients of the two processes specific to the transition in question, and the energy density of the radiation field at the frequency corresponding to the energy of the transition(s).